# How to get printf to write a new file, append an existing file, and write to stdout?

Tags: linux, bash, file-io, io, stdout

I have a `printf` command that will write a file but won't print to stdout. I would like to have both so I can let the user see what's happening, and at the same time, write a record to a log file.

`printf "%s\n" "This is some text" "That will be written to a file" "There will be several lines" | tee -a bin/logfile.log > bin/newfile.conf`

That command appends to the log file and writes to the new file, but writes no output to the screen :(

OS: Centos 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you're redirecting the screen output with `> bin/newfile.conf` in addition to what you're doing with `tee`. Just drop the `>` and everything after it. If you want to output to both of those files at once in addition to the screen, you can use `tee` twice, e.g.:

```
printf ... | tee -a bin/logfile.log | tee bin/newfile.conf
```

That appends to *logfile.log* and overwrites *newfile.conf*, and also writes out to the screen. Use or omit the `-a` option as needed.

As [John1024 points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44123460/how-to-get-prinf-to-write-new-file-append-to-existing-file-and-to-stdout/44123474?noredirect=1#comment75266439_44123474) you can also use `tee` once since it accepts multiple filenames, although in that case `-a` [applies to all filenames](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html),  but it can be useful in the case where you want the append vs. overwrite behavior to be the same for all files.

Comment: I actually need to go to 2 files, one as a new file (conf file), the other to append (log file), can i `tee` twice?

Comment: @bc81 Yes you can `tee` twice, and use `-a` for the ones you want to append. I fixed up the example. `tee` is like a "tap" in a "pipe", you can actually use it as many times as you want, at any point in a chain of piped commands, to dump the stream at that point to a file.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!

Comment: You can also just truncate the target file so that it is guaranteed to be empty before appending to it. `: > bin/newfile.conf; printf ... | tee -a bin/logfile.log bin/newfile.conf`. Slightly more typing, but fewer processes.